# Cognos - Promptmany with default selection 'ALL' not working

Tags: cognos

I have a report that uses SQL Query. I have a promptmany macro in the SQL:

```
#promptmany('countryParam', 'string', 'and 1=1' , 'and s.country in (', 'countryParam', ' )')#
```

This prompt has a default value `and 1=1` which should be passed if no value is selected.

On the prompt page, I have the prompt which displays all the countries.

I want the prompt to show `All` at the top of the list of countries in the prompt box. When the user selects `All` , no value should be passed in the SQL.

I have tried static choice to use blank and display to use `All`, but it passes blank value in the sql.

```
where s.country in ('')
```

It works with the prompt macro but dosent work with promptmany.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use Static choices.  For one option, Display 'All' and use 'All'.

In your filter:

case ?prompt1?
when 'All' then ( 1 = 1 )
else ( [do something here] )
end

Comment: I tried CASE in the where clause, but it only uses a specific format like c.country = case c.city when 'AUS' then 'Canberra' when 'IND' then 'DEL' END. The where clause is not very flexible

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of options, I was able to manipulate the SQL. The below SQL works

and (      #prompt('IJParam', 'string', '1=1' , 's.ij_code=')#
                                                or
                                 #promptmany('IJParam', 'string', ' 1=1' , ' s.ij_code in (', 'IJParam', ' )')#
                                )